# Install postgres on osx mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the postrgres application installed in Mavericks. It's running on port 5432.

I have a rails project which uses the pg gem.

However, when running "bundle install" I get this error:

```
    Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jonathanhurley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jonathanhurley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jonathanhurley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jonathanhurley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'd understand this error if postgres wasn't installed but it is.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) first, as it's a great package manager for OS X. You can install it with this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

After you get homebrew installed, you can then install postgresql with your `brew` command.

```
brew install postgresql
```

My coworker had the same issue you had yesterday, but after installing again with homebrew, it works as intended.